# Интеграция с ПОС Госуслуги (витрина), не могу отправить файл csv

Tags: php

Кто проходил этот слабо документированный квест, пожалуйста, откликнитесь. Речь идёт о Витрине ПОС Госуслуг, когда статистические данные о городских проблемах и жалобах отправляем из города --> в Москву.  Это вот [отсюда](https://pos.gosuslugi.ru/docs/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_%D0%92%D0%98%D0%A1_v8.docx)

Проблема: при отправке файла CSV на точку /analytic-service/statistic-data получаем ответ null со статусом 400. Пробовали отправлять и на тест, и на прод.

```
    $url="$gosusREST/analytic-service/statistic-data";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST , 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => $csv, "type"=>"application/vnd.ms-excel"]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$resultAuth["access_token"],
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            ));                    
    $rawdata=curl_exec($curl);
```

Ключи авторизации верные, далее получаем валидные токены, и даже приём есть, а передачи нет! Если поломать bearer, сервер ответит

> 401 {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication
> is required to access this resource"}

...то есть сервер жив. Но как понять пустой ответ 400 и что может быть у них не так?

Comment: фидлер ставили когда обычным способом отправляли? потом сравнивать когда через php

Comment: @Kvandaik не ставили. Что такое фидлер и "обычный способ отправки"? В документации на витрину про это не нашел.

Comment: Витрине ПОС Госуслуг это я так полагаю веб морда сайта куда стандартным способом можно подгрузить csv файл. По поводу фидлера погугли как пользоваться фидлером. Он расшивает трафик https и ты видишь что происходит когда отправляешь данные нажимая кнопку.

Comment: @Kvandaik в моё время это называли сниффером. Совет понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Успешный вариант отправки отличается в 3 местах: `file`, `ssl` и `httpauth`. Файл надо предварительно сохранить  на диск.

```
...
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => new CURLFile($tempFilename), "type"=>"application/vnd.ms-excel"]);//только так! а иначе 500
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");   //не надо
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);//чтобы выдало заголовки, но они тут неинформативные
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
...
```

А недокументированный код ответа 400, это если `file` пытаться послать прямым вложением.